# SQL: Learning How to Use The Percentile Functions in SQL

Tags: sql, r, netezza

I am working with **Netezza SQL.**

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    country VARCHAR(50),
    gender CHAR(1),
    age INTEGER,
    height FLOAT,
    owns_bicycle VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'M', 25, 175.99, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 63, 163.65, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 83, 166.01, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 94, 178.92, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'M', 63, 173.24, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 87, 156.27, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 89, 159.26, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 61, 179.14, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 49, 167.55, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 53, 172.82, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 62, 161.18, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 31, 173.08, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 33, 166.13, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 50, 177.42, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 57, 155.56, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'M', 57, 158.47, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 27, 152.85, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 89, 156.31, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 99, 179.31, 'No');
```

**My Problem:**

- First, I want to break height into 3 equal sized groups by value of their height (e.g. 0%-33%, 33%-66%,66%-99%).
- Next, I want to break age into 5 equal sized groups by value of their age (e.g. 0%-20%, 20%-40%, etc.)
- Then, for each unique combination of country, gender, age_group and height_group, I want to find out the percent of who own a bicycle.

The final result should look something like this (i.e. each person should only be assigned to one final subset):

```
  country gender height_group    age_group   bicycle_proportion counts
  <chr>   <chr>  <fct>           <fct>                    <dbl>  <int>
1 Canada  F      150.84 - 158.49 18 - 31                  0          2
2 Canada  F      150.84 - 158.49 31 - 45.2                0.333      3
3 Canada  F      150.84 - 158.49 62.4 - 78.4              0          2
4 Canada  F      150.84 - 158.49 78.4 - 99                0          1
5 Canada  F      158.49 - 169.33 18 - 31                  0          1
6 Canada  F      158.49 - 169.33 31 - 45.2                1          1
```

**I know how to do this using the  R programming language:**

```
library(dplyr)



set.seed(123)
n <- 100
country <- sample(c("USA", "Canada", "UK"), n, replace = TRUE)
gender <- sample(c("M", "F"), n, replace = TRUE)
age <- sample(18:100, n, replace = TRUE)
height <- runif(n, min = 150, max = 180)
owns_bicycle <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), n, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)


height_breaks <- quantile(df$height, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 1/3))
age_breaks <- quantile(df$age, probs = seq(0, 1, by = 1/5))

height_breaks <- round(height_breaks, 2)

height_labels <- paste0(height_breaks[-length(height_breaks)], " - ", height_breaks[-1])
age_labels <- paste0(age_breaks[-length(age_breaks)], " - ", age_breaks[-1])


df$height_group <- cut(df$height, breaks = height_breaks, labels = height_labels, include.lowest = TRUE)
df$age_group <- cut(df$age, breaks = age_breaks, labels = age_labels, include.lowest = TRUE)

final = df %>%
  group_by(country, gender, height_group, age_group) %>%
  summarise(bicycle_proportion = mean(owns_bicycle == "Yes"),
            counts = n())
```

**Now, I am trying to convert this into Netezza SQL.**

I am not sure how to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE height_groups AS
  SELECT
    NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY height) AS height_group,
    MIN(height) AS min_height,
    MAX(height) AS max_height
  FROM MY_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE age_groups AS
  SELECT
    NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY age) AS age_group,
    MIN(age) AS min_age,
    MAX(age) AS max_age
  FROM MY_TABLE;
```

**But I don't think I am doing this correctly.
Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `percentile_cont` or `percentile_disc` functions?
Here is the [documentation link](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=e-inverse-distribution-functions-2) 

PERCENTILE_CONT returns the value that corresponds to the specified percentile given a sort specification by using a continuous distribution model.
PERCENTILE_DISC returns the value that corresponds to the specified percentile given a sort specification by using a discrete distribution model.

Comment: @ Rajshekar Iyer: Thank you so much for your reply! This link looks very useful! If you have time, could you please show me how I can use these functions to achieve my desired result? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example use of some functions to arrive at the equivalent of your R code. It uses `percentile_cont` to arrive at the 2 boundary values between quantiles which can then be used in case expressions to arrive at height or age labels. The "cross join" simply adds these values to each table row for ease of use in the case expressions. (This is displayed further in the referenced fiddle below.)

```
SELECT
      t.country
    , t.gender
    , CASE WHEN t.height <= height_quantiles.q1 THEN 'short' 
           WHEN t.height <= height_quantiles.q2 THEN 'medium' 
           ELSE 'tall' 
      END AS height_group
    , CASE WHEN t.age <= age_quantiles.q1 THEN 'young' 
           WHEN t.age <= age_quantiles.q2 THEN 'middle_age' 
           ELSE 'old' 
      END AS age_group
    , AVG(CASE WHEN t.owns_bicycle = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bicycle_proportion
    , COUNT(*) AS counts
FROM MY_TABLE t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
          PERCENTILE_CONT(0.33) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY height) AS q1
        , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.67) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY height) AS q2
    FROM MY_TABLE t
    ) height_quantiles
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT
          PERCENTILE_CONT(0.2) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY age) AS q1
        , PERCENTILE_CONT(0.4) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY age) AS q2
    FROM MY_TABLE t
    ) age_quantiles
GROUP BY
      t.country
    , t.gender
    , height_group
    , age_group
ORDER BY
      t.country
    , t.gender
    , height_group
    , age_group
```

| country | gender | height_group | age_group | bicycle_proportion | counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Canada | F | medium | old | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| Canada | F | medium | young | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| Canada | F | short | old | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| Canada | F | tall | middle_age | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| Canada | M | short | old | 1.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| Canada | M | tall | old | 1.00000000000000000000 | 2 |
| UK | F | medium | middle_age | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| UK | F | medium | old | 0.50000000000000000000 | 2 |
| UK | F | short | middle_age | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| UK | F | short | old | 1.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| UK | F | short | young | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| UK | M | tall | old | 1.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| UK | M | tall | young | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| USA | F | medium | middle_age | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| USA | F | medium | young | 1.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| USA | F | tall | old | 0.00000000000000000000 | 1 |
| USA | M | short | middle_age | 1.00000000000000000000 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zimobgtF)

Re: An "adaptable" variant. SQL is not a programming language, it deals with sets of data, so mimicking the R code may be possible if you use a  "procedural extension" to SQL (e.g. plsql in Postgres) but as I'm not able to run anything in Netazza the best I can suggest is something along these lines.

```
with CTE as (
    SELECT
      *
     , NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY height) AS height_quantile
     , NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY age) AS age_quantile
    FROM my_table
 )
, height_labels as (
  select
       height_quantile hq
     , concat(floor(min(round(height::decimal,2))) , ' to '
            , max(ceiling(round(height::decimal,2)) ) ) height_label
  from CTE
 group by
       height_quantile
  )
, age_labels as (
  select
       age_quantile aq
     , concat(min(age ) , ' to '
            , max(age ) ) age_label
  from CTE
 group by
       age_quantile
  )
select
  *
from CTE 
inner join height_labels h on cte.height_quantile=h.hq
inner join age_labels    a on cte.age_quantile=a.aq
order by
    height, age
```

| country | gender | age | height | owns_bicycle | height_quantile | age_quantile | hq | height_label | aq | age_label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK | F | 27 | 152.85 | No | 1 | 1 | 1 | 152 to 159 | 1 | 25 to 33 |
| UK | F | 57 | 155.56 | No | 1 | 3 | 1 | 152 to 159 | 3 | 57 to 63 |
| Canada | M | 87 | 156.27 | Yes | 1 | 4 | 1 | 152 to 159 | 4 | 63 to 89 |
| UK | F | 89 | 156.31 | Yes | 1 | 5 | 1 | 152 to 159 | 5 | 89 to 99 |
| USA | M | 57 | 158.47 | Yes | 1 | 2 | 1 | 152 to 159 | 2 | 49 to 57 |
| Canada | F | 89 | 159.26 | No | 2 | 4 | 2 | 159 to 167 | 4 | 63 to 89 |
| Canada | F | 62 | 161.18 | No | 2 | 3 | 2 | 159 to 167 | 3 | 57 to 63 |
| UK | F | 63 | 163.65 | No | 2 | 3 | 2 | 159 to 167 | 3 | 57 to 63 |
| UK | F | 83 | 166.01 | Yes | 2 | 4 | 2 | 159 to 167 | 4 | 63 to 89 |
| USA | F | 33 | 166.13 | Yes | 2 | 1 | 2 | 159 to 167 | 1 | 25 to 33 |
| UK | F | 49 | 167.55 | No | 3 | 2 | 3 | 167 to 176 | 2 | 49 to 57 |
| USA | F | 53 | 172.82 | No | 3 | 2 | 3 | 167 to 176 | 2 | 49 to 57 |
| Canada | F | 31 | 173.08 | No | 3 | 1 | 3 | 167 to 176 | 1 | 25 to 33 |
| UK | M | 63 | 173.24 | Yes | 3 | 4 | 3 | 167 to 176 | 4 | 63 to 89 |
| UK | M | 25 | 175.99 | No | 3 | 1 | 3 | 167 to 176 | 1 | 25 to 33 |
| Canada | F | 50 | 177.42 | No | 4 | 2 | 4 | 177 to 180 | 2 | 49 to 57 |
| Canada | M | 94 | 178.92 | Yes | 4 | 5 | 4 | 177 to 180 | 5 | 89 to 99 |
| Canada | M | 61 | 179.14 | Yes | 4 | 3 | 4 | 177 to 180 | 3 | 57 to 63 |
| USA | F | 99 | 179.31 | No | 4 | 5 | 4 | 177 to 180 | 5 | 89 to 99 |

[The third fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lnk4XzdJ)

In this approach the labels are generated from the min/max pairs of each NTILE, and then those used in the final output. To simplify the label creation I introduced the functions floor and ceiling.

Comment: @ Paul Maxwell: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to make this more of a "generic answer" , e.g. instead of manually writing old, young etc... if i wanted to make 10 groups within age, i could just write group_1,group_2, etc? thank you so much!

Comment: @ Paul Maxwell: Thank you for your reply! What I meant - is there a way to avoid the "CASE WHEN" statement in your code? If I could just make it like age_group = 1,2,3,4 ... and then have a legend/lookup table to find out the min/max range for each age_group, height_group?

Comment: Not like you have done in R, you can concatenate strings but you need the elements to concatenate in the query. Or you can build a CTE or table of those labels. There are too many possibilities to describe all of them in a comment.

Comment: You can build-up tables of the boundary values (as I have done in my example) and these could carry labels, and then those joined to the source data perhaps using "between" as the join condition - but be careful not to multiply the number source rows by joining to multi-row tables i.e. a source row must only join to a boundary table row.

Comment: btw: "CASE WHEN" is not a "statement" they are "case expressions" as they evaluate to a single value (i.e. an "expression")

Comment: I have added an (incomplete) second option that allows easy change for the number of quantiles (using the NTILE(n) just change the n) and then generating labels. The accuracy of the math used in the labels I leave as an exercise for you.

Comment: @ Paul Maxwell: Thank you so much for your updates! I just posted a new answer ("second") to my own question (see below) - can you please take a look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Heres a simple example

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  marks INT
);

INSERT INTO students VALUES
(1, 'John', 90),
(2, 'Jane', 80),
(3, 'Mike', 70),
(4, 'Peter', 60);

SELECT
  id,
  name,
  marks,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(marks, 0.25) AS 25th_percentile,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(marks, 0.50) AS 50th_percentile,
  PERCENTILE_CONT(marks, 0.75) AS 75th_percentile
FROM students;
```

Comment: @ Rajshekar Iyer: Thank you so much for your answer! I posted a new answer to my own question (see below) - can you please take a look at it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OP here - here is my own attempt at solving my own problem.

I thought I can do this in 3 steps:

- Step 1: First, calculate the necessary percentile categories (e.g. 3 groups, 5 groups) based on height and age
- Step 2: Next, replace the values of height and age in the original table with these categories
- Step 3: Finally, make a legend/lookup table that contains the min/max of each category

I am not sure if this is correct (although it looks correct?).

**Can someone please provide opinions on this?**

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    country VARCHAR(50),
    gender CHAR(1),
    age INTEGER,
    height FLOAT,
    owns_bicycle VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'M', 25, 175.99, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 63, 163.65, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 83, 166.01, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 94, 178.92, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'M', 63, 173.24, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 87, 156.27, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 89, 159.26, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 61, 179.14, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 49, 167.55, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 53, 172.82, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 62, 161.18, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 31, 173.08, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 33, 166.13, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 50, 177.42, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 57, 155.56, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'M', 57, 158.47, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 27, 152.85, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 89, 156.31, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 99, 179.31, 'No');

CREATE TABLE height_groups AS
SELECT
  country,
  gender,
  NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY height) AS height_group,
  MIN(height) AS min_height,
  MAX(height) AS max_height
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY country, gender, height;

CREATE TABLE age_groups AS
SELECT
  country,
  gender,
  NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY age) AS age_group,
  MIN(age) AS min_age,
  MAX(age) AS max_age
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY country, gender, age;

CREATE TABLE final AS
SELECT
  h.country,
  h.gender,
  h.height_group,
  a.age_group,
  AVG(CASE WHEN t.owns_bicycle = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bicycle_proportion,
  COUNT(*) AS counts
FROM height_groups h
JOIN age_groups a ON h.country = a.country AND h.gender = a.gender
JOIN MY_TABLE t ON h.country = t.country AND h.gender = t.gender AND t.height BETWEEN h.min_height AND h.max_height AND t.age BETWEEN a.min_age AND a.max_age
GROUP BY h.country, h.gender, h.height_group, a.age_group;


CREATE TABLE lookup AS
SELECT
  h.country,
  h.gender,
  h.height_group,
  a.age_group,
  h.min_height,
  h.max_height,
  a.min_age,
  a.max_age
FROM height_groups h
JOIN age_groups a ON h.country = a.country AND h.gender = a.gender;
```

**Is what I have done correct?**

Answer (score 0):

OP again - I realized the age groups and height groups are not consistent in my previous answer (e.g. sometimes age_group = 1 will have different min/max heights).

Here is my second attempt - a more manual attempt (this time for 5 age groups and 5 height groups):

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (
    country VARCHAR(50),
    gender CHAR(1),
    age INTEGER,
    height FLOAT,
    owns_bicycle VARCHAR(3)
);

INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'M', 25, 175.99, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 63, 163.65, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 83, 166.01, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 94, 178.92, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'M', 63, 173.24, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 87, 156.27, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 89, 159.26, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'M', 61, 179.14, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 49, 167.55, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 53, 172.82, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 62, 161.18, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 31, 173.08, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 33, 166.13, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('Canada', 'F', 50, 177.42, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 57, 155.56, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'M', 57, 158.47, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 27, 152.85, 'No');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('UK', 'F', 89, 156.31, 'Yes');
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle)
VALUES ('USA', 'F', 99, 179.31, 'No');

CREATE TABLE age_groups AS
SELECT country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle,
NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY age) AS age_group
FROM MY_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE height_groups AS
SELECT country, gender, age, height, owns_bicycle,
NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY height) AS height_group
FROM MY_TABLE;

CREATE TABLE age_height_group_replacements AS
SELECT
    a.country,
    a.gender,
    a.age,
    a.height,
    a.owns_bicycle,
    CASE
        WHEN a.age BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 1) AND (SELECT MAX(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 1) THEN 'Group 1'
        WHEN a.age BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 2) AND (SELECT MAX(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 2) THEN 'Group 2'
        WHEN a.age BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 3) AND (SELECT MAX(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 3) THEN 'Group 3'
        WHEN a.age BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 4) AND (SELECT MAX(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = 4) THEN 'Group 4'
        ELSE 'Group 5'
    END AS age_group_replacement,
    CASE
        WHEN a.height BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 1) AND (SELECT MAX(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 1) THEN 'Group 1'
        WHEN a.height BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 2) AND (SELECT MAX(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 2) THEN 'Group 2'
        WHEN a.height BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 3) AND (SELECT MAX(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 3) THEN 'Group 3'
        WHEN a.height BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 4) AND (SELECT MAX(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = 4) THEN 'Group 4'
        ELSE 'Group 5'
    END AS height_group_replacement,
    (SELECT MIN(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = (SELECT age_group FROM age_groups WHERE age = a.age)) AS min_age,
    (SELECT MAX(age) FROM age_groups WHERE age_group = (SELECT age_group FROM age_groups WHERE age = a.age)) AS max_age,
    (SELECT MIN(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = (SELECT height_group FROM height_groups WHERE height = a.height)) AS min_height,
    (SELECT MAX(height) FROM height_groups WHERE height_group = (SELECT height_group FROM height_groups WHERE height = a.height)) AS max_height
FROM
    MY_TABLE a;

 CREATE TABLE BIKE_OWNERSHIP AS SELECT
    min_age,
    max_age,
    min_height,
    max_height,
    country,
    gender,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN owns_bicycle = 'Yes' THEN 1 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percentage_owns_bicycle
FROM
    age_height_group_replacements
GROUP BY
    min_age,
    max_age,
    min_height,
    max_height,
    country,
    gender;
```

Anyone have any comments on this?

Thanks!

Note: you can try to execute this SQL code here:  https://sqliteonline.com/

Comment: I think you have missed the point of NTILE. Re-look at https://dbfiddle.uk/lPtQcL1M You can use both NTILEs at the same time directly on the source table - and the values given by those function can then be used in case expression WTHOUT having to use (awkward/inefficient) "correlated subqueries" to figure out the min/max value pairs.  You really only need to calculate the labels - which can be done using "common table expressions" (cte)  to avoid making permanent tables.

Comment: I have updated the NTILE based portion of my answer so that the labels are a bit cleaner (using floor/ceiling functions). I hope you see that not only is this more flexible (as you don't need to hard code the labels) but also more efficient than many ["correlated subqueries"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)

Comment: @ Paul Maxwell: Thank you so much for your answer! I think I was able to convert my SQL into a CTE (Common Table Expression). Do you think I should post a new question and provide you a link with my attempt to write the CTE?

Comment: It isn't normal to be proposing answers and soliciting feedback as if this was a discussion forum. Typically you would wait for an answer and choose the best one. This is particularly so as you have also added bounty points to attract more answers.